# Can python functions defined inside class methods access self?

Tags: python

Taking this class as an example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute = 4

    def my_method(self):
        def my_fun(arg1, arg2):
            self.attribute = 7

        pass
```

should `my_fun` be allowed to access and change `self.attribute` ?

I can see that my editor does not colour `self` inside `my_fun`.

This is what I am trying to implement: `my_method` should call an external function that requires a callback taking two arguments, `arg1` and `arg2`. I would like to extend the functionality by allowing this callback to use variables declared inside `my_method`, and also make the `my_fun` callback write some debugging info to `self.log`. I am not quite sure if this is the right design for this type of problem.

Comment: Try it and see?

Comment: yes, this works, you just need to actually call `my_fun(val1,val2)` inside `my_method`. try playing around with `my_method` and actually run it a few times

Comment: Yes, but simply because that function creates a closure over the `self` identifier, which is referencing the instance, (if called as a method on an instance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. `self` is just another variable. It's python automatically passing in the reference to the instance as the first argument. Nothing more.

Your inner function will be able to access `self` as if it were a regular function that accesses a regular object.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute = 4

    def my_method(self):
        def my_fun():
            self.attribute = 7

        return my_fun

a = MyClass()
a.my_method()()
print(a.attribute)
```

Output:

```
7
```

The design you explain is fine; the one issue it has is "I would like to extend the functionality by allowing this callback to use variables declared inside `my_method`".

While you can access variables defined inside `my_method`, from a design standpoint variables that you want to save in a meaningful manner are better as attributes in the instance. You will be able to modify them and they "save" automatically, while if you want to  keep the results of things you define in `my_method` you will have to find another place to put them when the function call ends.

Comment: Any idea why the IDE doesn't like the `self` inside `my_fun` ?

Comment: @George It's an issue with the editor not with python. It's likely an edge case that the devs haven't covered yet.

Comment: @George report a bug to the IDE developers. Or, if it's open source, submit a patch (c: